# How long does a closed question remain in the "delete" queue?

Tags: discussion, support

With my current reputation I am able to cast 6 delete votes per day and I wonder how many days these posts remain on queue in the ["delete" tab from the Tools menu](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tools) (2k rep only), waiting for them to harvest the required [3 or more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/146318) votes (from different users) before being actually deleted.

Basically, because I became aware of this menu only after another user told me where to look, I'm afraid other users might be in the same situation, thus making my work meaningless if the questions pass unnoticed before expiring.

Since there are quite a few old questions closed as too broad/missing picture with zero answers, I estimate it will take me a few weeks to cover them all. That's why, before I embark on this task I'd like to know what setbacks I might encounter.

Comment: Thanks for asking this Alina! I've been wondering about this for a long time, but never took the time to ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete votes never expire (see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) and scroll down to the section "How do votes to delete work?").

The delete tab on the tools page has a maximum 30 day range and posts don't appear to get bumped if a new delete vote comes in later on (source: [Is there a way to "bump" deletion votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87037/is-there-a-way-to-bump-deletion-votes)).

So, following the recommendation in the answer on that second Q&A, I would mention it in chat whenever you cast a delete vote. Most of the people that are active on the site and have enough rep to cast delete votes are in the main chat room fairly regularly, so you can discuss the post with them if they have questions. Also, active discussion about deleting old Q&As is likely to attract other people that might otherwise not stop by.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that explaines why the questions have 1 recent vote (mine) from a total of 2. It seems somebody else has voted to delete them and more than 30 days have passed since.